# How to evaluate a Splunk field which represents the length of another field?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I've loaded the following example file containing lines of JSON into Splunk:

```json
{"duration":2134,"input":["foo","bar"],"level":"info","msg":"Processed input","time":"2022-04-07T08:10:23.14427-07:00"}
{"duration":997,"input":["baz"],"level":"info","msg":"Processed input","time":"2022-04-07T08:10:23.144526-07:00"}
```

Splunk has parsed these fields such that the `input` field is a list:
[image]
I would like to generate a table of the length of (number of elements in) the input and the `duration` field. Following https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/StreamProcessor/standard/FunctionReference/List#length.28input.29, I've tried

```
msg="Processed input" 
| eval N=length(input) 
| table N, duration
```

but this yields no values for `N`:

[image]

What would be the correct way to determine `N`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `mvcount('input{}')` in replace of `length(input)`

Edit: Put Single quotes around `input{}` as `{`,`}` are special characters.